# Conflict between titles mode of tocloft and tocbiding and etoc packages

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, etoc

I am having an issue when I use the [titles] mode of the `tocloft` package. I took care to load tocloft before `etoc`, but two problems remain. First, the titles instructions do not apply to the `etoctableofcontents` and, second, the `tocbidind` package does not apply to the `etoctableofcontents`, while everything works when I remove the [titles] mode but I then loose the ability to edit the titles. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage[section]{tocbibind}
\sectionfont{\centering}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\centering\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}


\begin{document}

\renewcommand*\contentsname{Sommaire}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{INTRODUCTION} \lipsum{1}
\chapter{METHODOLOGY} \lipsum{1}
\chapter{CONCLUSION} \lipsum{1}

\pagebreak
\listoffigures
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\listoftables
\endgroup

\pagebreak
\renewcommand*\contentsname{Tables des matières}
\etocsetnexttocdepth{subsubsection}
\etoctableofcontents

\end{document}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you are using `etoc` do you need `tocloft`? I tried deleting both `tocloft` and `tocbibind` and set the title using `\etocsettocstyle` but that seemed to have little effect on the title apart from its position.

Comment: In my comment above I was mistaken when I effectively said that `\etocsettocstyle` didn't completely work.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. With `\etocsettocstyle`, I think I will be able to modify the title, but concerning `tocbidind` you suggest that I add the entries of the first and the second ToC manually in each of them? Thanks

Comment: `tocbibind` seems to add the `tableofcontents` title to the `tableofcontents` but does nothing about the `etoctableofcontents`. Try putting `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\contentsname}` after the `\etoctableofcontents`. I have passed on the maintenance of `tocbibind` and it will be up to the current maintainer and the `etoc` author to sort out any problems.

Comment: Yes it is working perfectly now. Thanks. I just didn't manage to modify only the title with `\etocsettocstyle`, the mention "Table des matières" in my case, as when I put the arguments to the command it applies to the whole ToC. Do you know if there is a command to modify only the title of the ToC? Thanks again

Comment: `\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Your name}` changes the title name of the ToC. Have you thought of indicating some acceptance of my answer?

Comment: I tried to accept your first answer but I don't have a checkmark appearing next to it. My last question wasn't well worded. I have the following code and I wish that only the ToC title to be centred, bold and `\Large`:

```\etocsetnexttocdepth{subsubsection}
    \etocsettocstyle{\centering\Large\bfseries{Table des matières}}{}
    \etoctableofcontents
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Table des Matières}```

Comment: release `1.2` (`2023/03/01`) of [etoc](https://ctan.org/pkg/etoc) has compatibility with [tocbibind](https://ctan.org/pkg/tocbibind).